# Getting "403 : forbiden" on Team Founation Server over API Remote access

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-devops-server

I am trying to update my test results using the **Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client** nuget package.
Hence, I am using c# code.

I connect to our server using Personnal Access Token (PAT) having **full access**

Method called for update is the following :

```
 await TestManagementClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(new TestCaseResult[] { testResult }, Project.TeamProjectName, testRunId);
```

## Result

I am getting an exception saying only **Forbidden** (typically a **403 error**) but hold on, when I establish VPN connection on my PC (to our server), the same code works!!

Does anyone have an idea? Any missing permission or something like that?

Comment: are another methods works?

Comment: Yes for example this one `var testResult = await TestManagementClient.GetTestResultByIdAsync(Project.TeamProjectName, testRunId, testResultId);`

Comment: @CfassKing Are you able to access your server when you not establish VPN connection? Please try ti disable the firewall to see how's the result.